# How to update datasets without re-clustering the whole datatsets after clustering finished?

Tags: cluster-analysis

What I used is spectral clustering. What should I do to avoid clustering the whole datasets?

Answer (score 0):

There are papers on how to infer the spectral embedding for new data points, e.g.,

> Bengio, Y., Paiement, J. F., Vincent, P., Delalleau, O., Roux, N. L., & Ouimet, M. (2004). Out-of-sample extensions for lle, isomap, mds, eigenmaps, and spectral clustering. In Advances in neural information processing systems (pp. 177-184).

You can then assign them to the nearest k-means cluster and update the means.

But implementing this will require quite some coding work on your behalf. In particular, in order to get this *fast*.

Clustering isn't really meant to be updatable, and not is spectral embedding, so it is worth looking into alternate algorithms, and to reconsider your objective whether you really need to have this.